# Maven complains "cannot find symbol" during compile

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I am getting "cannot find symbol" whenever I compile my code .But when I do  a rebuild to my project and then compile it works.Dont know why this is happening I am assuming it is because of the import on BSLocal.

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\njayanthy\Desktop\WPS\BrowserStack "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=65122:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2018.2.4 clean compile package install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building BrowserStack 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ BrowserStack ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\njayanthy\Desktop\WPS\BrowserStack\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ BrowserStack ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ BrowserStack ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ BrowserStack ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ BrowserStack ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ BrowserStack ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ BrowserStack ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\njayanthy\Desktop\WPS\BrowserStack\target\test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/njayanthy/Desktop/WPS/BrowserStack/src/test/java/com/mtrustcompany/browserstack/TestBase.java:[29,31] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class BSLocal
[ERROR] /C:/Users/njayanthy/Desktop/WPS/BrowserStack/src/test/java/com/mtrustcompany/browserstack/TestBase.java:[31,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BSLocal
  location: class com.mtrustcompany.browserstack.TestBase
[ERROR] /C:/Users/njayanthy/Desktop/WPS/BrowserStack/src/test/java/com/mtrustcompany/browserstack/TestBase.java:[31,37] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable BSLocal
  location: class com.mtrustcompany.browserstack.TestBase
[ERROR] /C:/Users/njayanthy/Desktop/WPS/BrowserStack/src/test/java/com/mtrustcompany/browserstack/TestBase.java:[38,28] cannot find symbol
  symbol: method getClass()
[INFO] 4 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.625 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-24T09:45:19-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/538M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project BrowserStack: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/njayanthy/Desktop/WPS/BrowserStack/src/test/java/com/mtrustcompany/browserstack/TestBase.java:[29,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class BSLocal
[ERROR] /C:/Users/njayanthy/Desktop/WPS/BrowserStack/src/test/java/com/mtrustcompany/browserstack/TestBase.java:[31,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class BSLocal
[ERROR] location: class com.mtrustcompany.browserstack.TestBase
[ERROR] /C:/Users/njayanthy/Desktop/WPS/BrowserStack/src/test/java/com/mtrustcompany/browserstack/TestBase.java:[31,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable BSLocal
[ERROR] location: class com.mtrustcompany.browserstack.TestBase
[ERROR] /C:/Users/njayanthy/Desktop/WPS/BrowserStack/src/test/java/com/mtrustcompany/browserstack/TestBase.java:[38,28] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: method getClass()
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

this is the TestBase.java class

```
package com.mtrustcompany.browserstack;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.rmi.UnexpectedException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;


public class TestBase extends BSLocal {

    public static BSLocal bsLocal = BSLocal.getInstance();
    static URL serverUrl;

    public WebDriver getWebDriver() {
        return webDriver.get();
    }

    String className = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    static {
        try {
            ;
            serverUrl = new URL(String.format("http://%s:%s@%s/wd/hub", bsLocal.username, bsLocal.accessKey, bsLocal.server));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * ThreadLocal variable which contains the  {@link WebDriver} instance which is used to perform browser interactions with.
     */
    private ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

    /**
     * DataProvider that explicitly sets the browser combinations to be used.
     *
     * @param testMethod
     * @return Two dimensional array of objects with browser, version, and platform information
     */
    @DataProvider(name = "browsers", parallel = true)
    public static Object[][] sauceBrowserDataProvider(Method testMethod) {
        return new Object[][]{
                new Object[]{"firefox", "65.0", "Windows 10"},
                new Object[]{"chrome", "70", "windows 10"},

        };
    }

    /**
     * @return the {@link WebDriver} for the current thread
     */


    protected void createDriver(String browser, String version, String os, String methodName)
            throws MalformedURLException, UnexpectedException {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // Note: zero based!
        int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, month - 1, day, 0, 0);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy  hh");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("build", String.format("%s %s", className, format.format(c.getTime())));
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, browser);
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, version);
        capabilities.setCapability("name", methodName);
        capabilities.setCapability("browserstack.local", "true");

        webDriver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(
                serverUrl,
                capabilities));

    }


    @AfterTest
    public void done() {
        bsLocal.stop();
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void mailTestReport() {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("", "");
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("jayanthymohit6@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(""));
            message.setSubject(String.format("%s %s", className, new Date()));
            BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart1.setText("Test Results");
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
            String filename = "C:\\Users\\njayanthy\\Desktop\\WPS\\BrowserStack\\test-output\\emailable-report.html";
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
            messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
            message.setContent(multipart);
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("=====Email Sent=====");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

I am not able to understand why this is happening , and what happens in the manual project build in the ide that runs the compile without any issues ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>MTC</groupId>
<artifactId>BrowserStack</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>automate-testassist</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-alpha-4</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>browserstack-local-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.saucelabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>sauce_testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.23</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <threadCount>40</threadCount>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>automate-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you provide the pom.xml <dependencies> section? I'm assuming that there is something missing.

Comment: added the pom.xml

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce. How are you compiling it.

Comment: mvn testCompile as my code is in src/test/java .When I build the project manually through the ide, the target/test-classes are generated and compile works fine .But when I do it without manually building it , and do a mvn test or install or package it fails.

Comment: Does your IDE use the same maven binaries that are installed on your system? (IntelliJ/Idea come with a bundled maven)